# Docker-compose - Starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, swagger

My docker service swagger was building nicely up util today, when I performed `docker system prune` in order built it all of my services from scratch again. Now this particular service, and only it, fails with the following error:

```
Building swagger
Step 1/10 : FROM nginx:1.15.8-perl
 ---> 7bb959be99b4
Step 2/10 : ENV SWAGGER_UI_VERSION 3.20.4
 ---> Running in 364ca6ef9b60
Removing intermediate container 364ca6ef9b60
 ---> 88aa04baa745
Step 3/10 : ENV URL **None**
 ---> Running in 3d48c38f7db0
Removing intermediate container 3d48c38f7db0
 ---> 76799da3d2d3
Step 4/10 : RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y curl     && curl -L https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/v${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar -zxv -C /tmp     && cp -R /tmp/swagger-ui-${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html     && rm -rf /tmp/*
 ---> Running in 6199b5dbdc9b

ERROR: Service 'swagger' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

---

*Structure*

```
docker-compose.yml
                 /
                 swagger/
                        Dockerfile-dev
                        start.sh
                        nginx.conf
                        swagger.json
```

---

*Files*

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  swagger:
    build:
      context: ./services/swagger
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
    - './services/swagger/swagger.json:/usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.json'
    ports:
      - 3008:8080
    environment:
    - URL=swagger.json
    depends_on:
      - web
```

**Dockerfile-dev**

```
FROM nginx:1.15.8-perl

ENV SWAGGER_UI_VERSION 3.20.4
ENV URL **None**

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl \
    && curl -L https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/v${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}.tar.gz | tar -zxv -C /tmp \
    && cp -R /tmp/swagger-ui-${SWAGGER_UI_VERSION}/dist/* /usr/share/nginx/html \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

COPY swagger.json /usr/share/nginx/html/swagger.json
COPY start.sh /start.sh

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/start.sh"]
CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $URL != "**None**" ]; then
  sed -i -e 's@https://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json@'"$URL"'@g' /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
fi

exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

I don't what is happening.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Have you restarted Docker?

Comment: yes I have...same error

Comment: are you mounting any volumes? https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/561

Comment: yes, please refer to my edit, `docker-composer.yml`

Comment: I'm able to run `docker run -it nginx:1.15.8-perl /bin/sh` without any errors so I would try rebooting and run `docker system prune -a`